# Prepare UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my tableView one of cell's kind not visible in the top of tableView. So when I scroll my tableView I see lag when cell appear. In iPhone 4 it is very big lag. So when tableView dequeue my cells, there are no problem, but when it in first load them form nib, I see lag.

Now I use in viewDidLoad

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([MovieDescriptionEventsCell class]) bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MovieDescriptionEventsCell class])];
```

So for first 6-8 cells there are lags because they are loaded from nib. How can I create cells before they appear in tableView?

EDIT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    /////
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        MovieDescriptionEventsCell *cell = (MovieDescriptionEventsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MovieDescriptionEventsCell class])];
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.maxNumberEvents = eventsMaxNumber;
        cell.partPlace = currentDayEvents.partPlaceEvents[indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

All magic in cell, but there are no lags after tableview create 6-8 cells (depends from size of cell), only when they are created.

Comment: Could you show your `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` code?

Comment: Can you share your cell's .m file.... u might be drawing something there

Answer (score 0):

Create it in `viewDidLoad`,

store its pointer in dataSource member(for example `slowCell`),

return it in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`